# Limit Google search result pages to those containing a specific string

Tags: google, search

Before Google started the Google Plus social media service, I could use +"a string" to ensure all result pages contain "a string" of my choosing, and I could use - to ensure it *doesn't* contain "a string". Since then, Google says to put double-quotes around the string to do the same thing. Well, it's not symmetrical, like using +, but if it would work, that would be fine.

The problem is that it *doesn't* work. I search for "a string"; get a set of result pages; go into the first one; do a Find within page for "a string" and there are 0 matches. The problem occurs repeatedly with various search keys. Using + the old way also doesn't work; I'm not sure what it does.

So, how do I insist that my result pages contain my string? Did we really go backwards in capability?

Comment: Sorry, is this issue specifically about Google Search on Android, or Google Search in general (web)? Note that there's a sister site [webapps.se] for issues regarding Google Search web in general. Though, as far as my experience goes, "double quote" usually works well to force search that keyword, *only if the page hasn't changed nor cheated the SEO by keyword spamming*.

Comment: I just tried to search dozes times using varying keys, each time doing a Find in Page for the quoted term and have found the term on the page only when the search key is very simple & straightforward (easily findable). That doesn't imply "working well" to me.